# count common entries between two string variables via Python

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I would greatly appreciate someones help with counting the number of matching state names from two columns in my csv file. For instance consider the first 7 observations from columns `State_born_in` and `state_lives_in`:

```
State_born_in   State_lives_in
New York    Florida
Massachusetts   Massachusetts
Florida Massachusetts
Illinois    Illinois 
Iowa    Texas
New Hampshire   Massachusetts
California  California
```

Basically I want to count the number of people who lived in the same state they were born in. I then want the percentage of all people who live in the same state they're born in. So in the example above I would have a count = 2 since there are two people that live in the same state they were born in(California and Massachusetts) who live in the same state they were born in. And if I wanted the percentage I would just divide 2 by the number of observations. I'm still relatively new to using pandas but this is what I've tried so far

```
df = pd.read_csv("uscitizens.csv","a")
import pandas as pd 
counts = df[(df['State_born_in'] == df['state_lives_in'])] ; counts
percentage = counts/len(df['State_born_in'])
```

Moreover, how would I do this on a dataset that has over 2 million observations? I would greatly appreciate anyone's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then simple divide `length` of filtered `DataFrame` with `length` of original (it is same as length of `index`, what is fastest):

```
print (df)
   State_born_in State_lives_in
0       New York        Florida
1  Massachusetts  Massachusetts
2  Massachusetts  Massachusetts
3  Massachusetts  Massachusetts
4        Florida  Massachusetts
5       Illinois       Illinois
6           Iowa          Texas
7  New Hampshire  Massachusetts
8     California     California

same = df[(df['State_born_in'] == df['State_lives_in'])] 
print (same)
   State_born_in State_lives_in
1  Massachusetts  Massachusetts
2  Massachusetts  Massachusetts
3  Massachusetts  Massachusetts
5       Illinois       Illinois
8     California     California

counts = len(same.index)
print (counts)
5

percentage = 100 * counts/len(df.index)
print (percentage)
55.55555555555556
```

**Timings**:

```
In [21]: %timeit len(same.index)
The slowest run took 18.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 546 ns per loop

In [22]: %timeit same.shape[0]
The slowest run took 21.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 µs per loop

In [23]: %timeit len(same['State_born_in'])
The slowest run took 46.92 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop
```

---

Faster solution:

```
same = (df['State_born_in'] == df['State_lives_in'])
print (same)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
dtype: bool

counts = same.sum()
print (counts)
5

percentage = 100 * counts/len(df.index)
print (percentage)
55.5555555556
```

**Timings** in 2M DataFrame:

```
#[2000000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*200000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)


In [127]: %timeit (100 * (df['State_born_in'] == df['State_lives_in']).sum()/len(df.index))
1 loop, best of 3: 444 ms per loop

In [128]: %timeit (100 * len(df[(df['State_born_in'] == df['State_lives_in'])].index)/len(df.index))
1 loop, best of 3: 472 ms per loop
```

Comment: thank you! By any chance, how could I do this for a large dataset that contains around 2 million observations?

Comment: I think you can use this solution - it can works nice with large dataframe. Or there is some problem?

Comment: I fixed it :), basically I rewrote `df = pd.read_csv("uscitizens.csv","a")`  to `with open('uscitizens.csv', 'r') as f:` so that it treated it as an object instead of storing the memory. But I followed your approach and did `line[2] == line[3]` where line[2] is `State_born_in` and line[3] is `state_lives_in`Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this?

```
counts = df[ df['State_born_in'] == df['State_lives_in'] ].groupby('State_born_in').agg(['count']).sum()
counts / len(df['State_born_in'])
```